# Why is react-microsoft-login giving me a CORS error?

Tags: azure, cors, microsoft-entra-id

I'm trying to use [react-microsoft-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-microsoft-login) to authenticate my React App. I have gone through the process linked to in the docs and followed Microsoft's tutorial for how to setup an app registration. Then created this App.tsx for my react app.

```
import MicrosoftLogin from "react-microsoft-login";

const CLIENT_ID = " ... using Application (client) ID from Microsoft Entra ID app registration ... "
const END_POINT = " ... using OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (v2) from the endpoints list ..."
const REDIRECT_URL = "... my website root domain page ..."

export default (props:any) => {
  console.log(props)
  const authHandler = (err:any, data:any) => {
    console.log(err, data);
  };  

  return (
    <MicrosoftLogin
      clientId={CLIENT_ID}
      tenantUrl={END_POINT}
      redirectUri={REDIRECT_URL}
      authCallback={authHandler}
      >   
    </MicrosoftLogin>
  );  
};
```

When I click the login button, I get an error in the console complaining about a CORS setting.

[image]

I'm not sure how to add a no-cors header when the library is making the request on my behalf and I think it should have settings to handle that if it's needed but they don't. So I imagine I've done something else wrong.

Comment: How is the redirect URI is configured in Azure AD app? I have seen this happening when the redirect URI is configured as a web application instead of Single-page application.

Comment: It's configured as a SPA. I have tried both actually. I've had luck not using the END_POINT but changing the settings in Azure to be a multi-tenant rather than single-tenant app registration. Though for my application single tenant makes the most sense as this is an internal tool

Comment: Try adding headers as `headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }` and check